# List in the view the total count of Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need help figuring out how to do the total count of users from the Questions table (based on `sender_id`) with what their gender is (from User's table `gender` attribute).

The example for output in the view would be:

```
345 males have asked a Question
221 females have asked a Question
```

I am working from the Questions model, but need to make the connection to the Users model to determine if the user is a male or female based on their `sender_id` from the Questions table and `gender` from the Users table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count_of_males = Question.joins(:user).where(users: {gender: 'male'}).uniq.count`

Which you can then modify for the female count, as well.

This assumes that you have a `belongs_to :user` in your Question class, and that you only want to count each user once, even though they may have asked many questions.